# How to exit IIf() statement when no value is present

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to terminate an `IIf()` statement if it doesn't return a value?

This is what my code looks like:

```
Do While Sheets("testsheet").Cells(1, Z) <> ""
  text1 = Sheets("testsheet").Cells(1, Z).Value
  vLook = Application.HLookup(text1, lookupRange, u, False)
  Sheets("Kilepok").Cells(i, Z).Value = IIf(IsError(vLook), ????, vLook)
  Z = Z + 1
Loop
```

The code runs through the header (z), and looks for a value. If it finds a value, I would like to paste this in those cases (when there is no error in vlook). In other cases, I don't want to modify the value of the current cell.

Comment: That's not how `Iif` works. To only execute the True (or False) part, use a regular `If ... Then ... Else ... End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
Sheets("Kilepok").Cells(i, Z).Value = IIf(IsError(vLook), Sheets("Kilepok").Cells(i, Z).Value, vLook)
```

or

```
If Not IsError(vLook) Then Sheets("Kilepok").Cells(i, Z).Value = vLook
```

will do the job.

But note that the first will re-write the cell's value (which makes it slow) and if there is a forumla in it, it will be converted into a value. So the second one would be the preferred solution.